# Can J.J. Abrams actually play the keyboard?

Tags: music-video, jj-abrams

In the Lonely Island music video for Cool Guys Don't Look At Explosions, [J.J. Abrams does a keyboard solo](https://youtu.be/Sqz5dbs5zmo?t=89).

Can he actually play the keyboard, and is it really him playing the keyboard on the song?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, JJ Abrams has been [credited](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0009190/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1#soundtrack) for writing on various sound tracks, mainly theme songs (*Alias, LOST, Fringe*) on some of his production company's (Bad Robot Productions) works.

He's even created/wrote the "Dobra Doompa" alien song featured in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*.

And it has been revealed that he likes collecting [electronic keyboards](https://nofilmschool.com/2016/07/5-things-we-learned-about-jj-abrams-new-video)!

As for the music video, according to [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_Guys_Don%27t_Look_at_Explosions) JJ Abrams did perform the keyboard solo, but it only sites the music video itself as the source. I have yet to find something more substantial to back it up.

> "Cool Guys Don't Look at Explosions" **is a song performed by Andy
>   Samberg, Will Ferrell, and J. J. Abrams at the 2009 MTV Movie Awards**.
>   It is a soft rock song dedicated to a popular film cliche in which
>   characters are depicted leaving the scene of an explosion unfazed by
>   the destruction behind them.

Comment: What a great answer! Somehow, knowing that he is actually playing, makes it even funnier.

Comment: I will keep searchingto see if I can find more evidence, but it does seem like he played it, but I suspect the Q is going to get closed as "trivia". You could always try your luck on Music Fans Stack Exchange: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/